# CultureInfo with several datetime representations

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Assume we have a WCF service which takes some `DateTime` object and works with it and we have a client which sends it in format `dd/mm/yyyy`. But this service is also called from JS which should send exact `DateTime`, this is why it is using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz` format.

Is it possible to create a Culture which is taking two formats and do no write disgusting `if`s like `if (DateTime.TryParse(format1, out dt) || DateTime.TryParse(format2, out dt) || DateTime.TryParse(format3, out dt) || ...)`

Another disadvantage of this code is that we also have to duplicate it for `DateTimeOffset` as well

Comment: TryParseExact will take an array of formats allowing you to check all at once

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Plutonix that's suits me, thank you. Of course I should write additional logic for `DateTimeOffset` and process it differently than other types, but there is no better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how ASP.NET MVC handles the issue. I think the same principles apply to a service implemented using another technology such as WCF. These conventions are used by web services.

ASP.NET MVC (including Web API) performs a culture-insensitive parsing on parameters passed in the querystring. Therefore, dates in the URL have to be in the universal format yyyy-mm-dd. Form values (or any value in request body) are expected to be in the format specified by the server. This means that a server set to the UK culture will expect dates to be in the UK date format: dd-mm-yyyy.

Why is culture-insensitive parsing performed on items in the URL?

There is a very good, logical and convenient reason why culture-insensitive parsing is performed on items in the URL. Imagine I see an item on sale and the sale has `from` and `to` dates in the URL. If I email that link to my friend (I live in Canada) in Germany, I want them to see the same page. If a culture-sensitive parse was performed on the date in the URL, my friend may be presented a totally different sale or may be presented a page not found-that will not be good.

So to answer your question, the client calling your WCF service should provide the date to your service in the format specified by the service unless the date is in the URL in which case the client should provide it in the universal format yyyy-mm-dd.

Another option is for the client to provide the culture to the service, for example, in the SOAP header, and the service will use that culture when parsing.

Comment: It's the same thing like passing header but without this header because you always can detect automatically which format is used. Of course it is not working when you have `11-12-2016` vs `12-11-2016`, but in this case you have `11-12-2016` vs `2016-12-11T15:55:45.555+03:00`, there is no way to mix up these two.