# Date Format Client Validation - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, date

So, I am new to mvc, .net, etc and I got the usual problem with the Date Format. I started by using data annotations on my model

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

my Create.cshtml looks like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to create an object, when I put a date in the format dd/MM/yyyy I got this error message from the jquery validation:

> The field Release Date must be a date.

When I tried a date of the format MM/dd/yyyy, and clicked the Create button I got that message from the server validator:

> The value '5/28/2013' is not valid for Release Date.

So with either format there was a conflict with one of the validators.
After a lot of research the only way that I could make it work was overriding the jquery validation with a custom script (tried a couple that I found here). I ended up using John Reilly's [globalize](https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize) which is based on the [globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#readme) by The jQuery Project and on the [jQuery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation). 
Followed the instructions and everything works. All the objects are created, no conflicts between the formats.

My modifications are:

Webconfig:

```
  <system.web>
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

(I will include them in a bundle if I keep using that solution.)

The only problem is that the client side validation is gone. Not just the date validation, but the validation of every field. For example, if I have a Required string field and don't put anything in it, I don't get the js error message that I used to get about the field being required. Or if I put "asdasdasd" in the Date field I don't get any js error. I get errors only after I click Create, from the server validator.

So, any ideas on how to get the client side validation back?

Thanks

PS: My knowledge on js is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to sync the client side date format with the server side date format. If you want a certain format on the client side, then you can instruct JQuery's datepicker to use that format. But do not expect the server to also use that exact format.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348323/cultureinfo-with-several-datetime-representations/41349064#41349064) where I explain in detail how MVC deals with dates.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get the example you use about the different countries at the other post but I don't get how that applies to my case. Right now the client/server formats are synced. The server asks for for dd/MM/yyyy and the client asks for dd/MM/yyyy too. My problem is that now the client doesn't give any error messages like it used to.

Comment: My whole point is that your issue arises from the fact that you are trying to sync them and that is not a good solution. If you remove all the JQuery code you wrote for syncing, then your issue will no longer exist. The whole idea is not to sync them.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I need. I need both of them to use the local format.